# На Ubuntu 17.04 не устанавливается ничего, не работает apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, apt-get, apt

Всем привет, недавно взял комп знакомого, т.к. мой сломался, здесь стоит Убунту и естественно переставить я ее не могу. Проблема в том, что я не могу поставить сюда НИЧЕГО!!! Я очень долго шерстил гугл в поисках решения, но ничего не нашел, итак. Для начала я естесвенно пробовал юзать apt-get install (я делал update неоднократно, ситуацию не меняет) при попытке установки любой программы я получаю это

```
"E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

Гуглил это, советовали autoremove, dpkg --get-selections, aptitude (поставить который я не могу), в общем я всё это делал, пробовал менять репозитории, но не получилось, вылезает окно

```
"Failed to download repository information"
```

Решение этого я естественно тоже гуглил, но ничего не помогло, при поытке установки обновлений вылезает она же.

Так же я пробовал устанавливать deb пакеты через dpkg -i, вылезает еще одна ошибка:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-5.2:i386
```

VirtualBox для примера, хотя именно ее мне и необходимо поставить.

В перерыл много чего, но либо ничего не нашел (видимо во мне дело)))

Прошу о помощи ибо это ВиртуалБокс мне необходима и ничего другим пользоваться я не могу (ДЗ для универа надо сделать)

Жду ваших комментариев и ответов, все предоставлю, что попросите)

Comment: А просто через магазин приложений поставить?

Comment: В магазине кнопка "Установить" просто не работает, ничего не происходит

Comment: А `apt-get install -f` чё нить делает интересное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему решил. В source.list для apt-get нужно было заменить в адресах ...achieve.ubuntu... на ...old-releases.ubuntu..., работает для старых релизов (у меня 17.04).

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сначала посмотреть список битых пакетов командой:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold
```

Затем исправить командой (для каждого пакета в списке)

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>
```

После этого может потребоваться переустановить конфликтующие пакеты

Обсуждалось здесь:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages